# Apache Camel sending marshalled data

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jms

I'm trying to send marshalled data through a Camel route. I've checked a few tutorials but can't get it to work and receive a `RuntimeException`.

What I want to accomplish:

- Extract the body of the message.
- Create a POJO with `content` and `title` fields.
- Marshall the POJO and send it further along the route.

```
@Override
public void configure() {
    from("Foo")
        .bean(TestMessageTransformer.class, "testMessageTransform")
        (1).marshal()
        .to("Bar")
```

```
public class TestMessage {

    private String content;
    private String title;

    public TestMessage(String content, String title) {
        this.content = content;
        this.title = title;
    }

}
```

```
public class TestMessageTransformer {

    @Bean("testMessageTransform")
    public TestMessage transform(String message) {
        return new TestMessage(message, "title");
    }

}
```

(1) I've tried using `marshal().jaxb()`, `marshal()` with `JacksonXMLDataFormat` but no dice.

Comment: Haven't tried to use jaxb without schemas yet but posted some tips on how to use jaxb with Apache Camel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71423226/how-to-generate-jaxb-data-format-from-xsd-schema/71480559#71480559). JacksonXML is probably easier than jaxb which seems to require a lot more knowledge and effort to use.  The documentation and tutorials for jaxb are severly lacking especially with the javax -> jakarta change.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the exception you get?

You may need to add public getters to TestMessage for the marshaller to get the fields.